# PHP Create a new array from value count

Tags: php, arrays

My original array is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-29
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-30
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[47] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[48] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[49] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[50] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[51] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[53] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[54] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[55] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[56] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[57] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[58] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[59] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[60] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[61] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[62] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[63] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[64] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[65] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[66] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[67] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[68] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[69] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[70] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[71] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[72] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[73] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[74] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[75] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[76] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 0
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[77] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

[78] => Array
    (
        [tracking_isbot] => 1
        [tracking_date] => 2015-08-31
    )

)
```

I'm trying to create a function which returns a new array which can latter be used in a chart, the code of the function I created is as below:

```
function chartData($results) {
$data = array();
$bots = 1;
$human = 1;
foreach($results as $subresults) {
    if($subresults['tracking_isbot'] === 1) {
        $data['bots'][$subresults['tracking_date']] = $bots++;
    } else {
        $data['human'][$subresults['tracking_date']] = $human++;
    }
}
return $data;
}
```

The data which I getting back from the above function are incorrect:

```
Array
(
[human] => Array
    (
        [2015-08-29] => 9
        [2015-08-30] => 27
        [2015-08-31] => 53
    )

[bots] => Array
    (
        [2015-08-29] => 6
        [2015-08-30] => 12
        [2015-08-31] => 26
    )

)
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: You could start by telling us what your array should look like.

Comment: Can you please post your expected output

Comment: `The data which I getting back ... are incorrect` And what is correct data?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: Array
(
    [human] => Array
        (
            [2015-08-29] => 9
            [2015-08-30] => 18
            [2015-08-31] => 26
        )

    [bots] => Array
        (
            [2015-08-29] => 6
            [2015-08-30] => 6
            [2015-08-31] => 14
        )

) ---- thanks to MPH and user for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function chartData($results) {

    $newArray = array('human' => array(), 'bots' => array());

    foreach($results as $index => $result) {
        if($result['tracking_isbot'] == 1) {
            if(isset($newArray['bots'][$result['tracking_date']])) {
                $newArray['bots'][$result['tracking_date']] += 1;
            } else {
                $newArray['bots'][$result['tracking_date']] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            if(isset($newArray['human'][$result['tracking_date']])) {
                $newArray['human'][$result['tracking_date']] += 1;
            } else {
                $newArray['human'][$result['tracking_date']] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

You're trying to count the number of human/bots per `tracking_date`, if I'm correct then the above function will do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I suppose your count is incorrect, which makes absolutely sense to me, as you are summing up everything and putting it into the array...

I try to explain:
You are increasing the $bots and $human value every time they are hit and pushing it into the value. This sums up pretty fast then and leads to a acount at this point - not the count of data for this date.

try this:

```
function chartData($results) {
    $data = array();

    foreach($results as $subresults) {
        $date = $subresults['tracking_date'];
        $key = 'human';

        if($subresults['tracking_isbot'] === 1) {
            $key = 'bots';
        } 

        if(!array_key_exists($date, $data[$key]))
            $data[$key][$date] = 1;
        else
            $data[$key][$date]++;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Hope this helps